# Django: Static files missing when rendering template

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, static-files, django-1.3

I am using django 1.3 and trying to deploy a django project (client sent) on my dev machine (ubuntu 12.04). The problem is regarding the static files. My **directory structure** is as follows:

```
project_name
    media
    static
        css
        img
        js
    settings.py
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
ROOT = '/home/user/project_name'

MEDIA_ROOT = '%s/media/' % ROOT
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '%s/static/' % ROOT
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

My site is perfectly deployed but the css, js and imgs are missing. Same is the case for the admin interface. When I use the link http://mysite.com/static/js/some.js it gives a 404.

Help would be appreciated and up-voting an answer is custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention configuring your web server to actually serve the static files. You need to point it at the directory that collectstatic put them into.

Comment: you mean in the main urls.py ? Please explain your answer

Comment: No, not in urls.py, because as the documentation explicitly explains, Django does *not* serve your static files in production. That is why I stated that you need to configure your web server to do it. Again, if you've read enough docs to know that you need to run staticfiles, this is explained in the exact same place.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to run `./manage.py collectstatic` :)

Comment: sadly i did but no success :(

Comment: Do you have 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder' in your STATICFILES_FINDERS?

Comment: yes i have STATICFILES_FINDERS in the settings.py with its default behavior

Answer (score 1):

did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` ? see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/)

be careful that in production you should place the static file in a static server. There should be something in the guidelines.

Comment: sadly i did but no success :(

Comment: what if u set `STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'` ?

Comment: Static root is just for production you shouldn't match it like that

Answer (score 0):

And a little offtopic..
It will be better, to use:
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),'media').replace('\','/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),'static').replace('\','/')

and in main urls.py at development, django webserver only:
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P.*)','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),'media').replace('\','/') }),
    (r'^static/(?P.*)','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),'static').replace('\','/')}),

In this way, u don`t need collectstatic, u`ll need it at production server, where u will use nginx or something other to server your static